# Filter rows based on one column from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of multiple data frames and I would like to filter these data frames in a list by certain values in one column of each data frame. Each data frame in the list has a column called *v1*, which has special characters *++, ->*, Now I do want to filter only rows having this *arrow (->)* in each data frame in a list. This is a sample of my dataframes,

```
dput(df)
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("->", "++", "->"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c("++", "->", "->"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
dput(df3)
df3 <- structure(list(v1 = c("++", "++", "->"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg"),
                      d3...c = c("James","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

I have tried this but I am not getting the dataframes of filtered rows

```
idx = "->"
dfs <- list(df1,df2,df3)
lapply(dfs, function(x) x$v1 %in% idx)
```

someone help

Comment: You're almost there. Your anonymous function must return what you want, which is a data.frame. What is in `idx`? I'll assume it is your target, i.e. `idx <- "++"`. The expression `x$v1 %in% idx` is a logical (boolean) vector, which you can use to subset the data.frame. The df is `x[x$v1 %in% idx,]`.

Comment: @antoine-sac I getting this error *Error in x$v1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
idx <- "->"

# Base R
lapply(dfs, function(df) df[df$v1 == "->",])
lapply(dfs, function(df) df[df$v1 %in% idx,])

# tidyverse

library("purrr")
library("dplyr")

map(dfs, filter, v1 == "->")
map(dfs, filter, v1 %in% !! idx)
```

Comment: I am getting this error * Error in x$v1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors *

Comment: There is no `x` in my answer so I am not sure what you ran.

Comment: sorry it is  Error in df$v1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: In the example you posted, `dfs` is a list of data.frames so the code works. I suspect you are mistakenly  using a data.frame (and not a list) as `dfs`. Since a data.frame is technically a list of atomic vectors, you will get this error.

Comment: sure that was the problem. I have fixed.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
idx <- "->"
fnct <- function(df){df <- df[df$v1 %in% idx, ]}
df1_idx <- fnct(df1)
df2_idx <- fnct(df2)
df3_idx <- fnct(df3)
dfs <- list(df1_idx, df2_idx, df3_idx)
dfs
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
  v1    t2
1 -> James
3 ->   Egg

[[2]]
  v1   t2
2 -> Jane
3 ->  Egg

[[3]]
  v1  t2 d3...c
3 -> Egg    Egg
```